# Why does my API Gateway Proxy integration produce 'response body' Cloudwatch logs that are not readable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have an API Gateway Rest API created with CDK with a proxy Http Integration that I've enabled full request/response CloudWatch logs for.

All of the logs look fine except for the `Endpoint response body before transformations` and `Method response body after transformations` logs, which look like this:

- `(a8f799d1-6a98-4467-9a72-56ecf9f2e17d) Endpoint response body before transformations: ��UmO�8�+Q���....`
- `(a8f799d1-6a98-4467-9a72-56ecf9f2e17d) Method response body after transformations: ��UmO�8�+Q���....`

The client receives the response body just fine. Is this purposefully hashed/encrypted, or am I missing some configuration to parse that properly in the logs?

Perhaps something to do with needing to map the response/request to `application/json`? This is just a direct proxy passthrough so I cant imagine I would need to map any of that.

CDK Proxy code looks like so:

```
api.root.addProxy({
  anyMethod: true,
  defaultMethodOptions: {
    requestParameters: {
      ['method.request.path.proxy']: true
    },
  },
  defaultIntegration: new HttpIntegration(`${endpoint}/{proxy}`, {
    httpMethod: 'ANY',
    options: {
      requestParameters: {
        ['integration.request.path.proxy']: 'method.request.path.proxy'
      },
      cacheKeyParameters: [
        'method.request.path.proxy'
      ]
    }
  })
})
```

I would like to see potential error messages and information from the body response here

Comment: Response body looks like a binary content. Maybe endpoint response is only compressed, so it is not plain text response.

Comment: @JanGaraj The client receives the response in JSON in this scenario, so just the logs are binary? Also if I hit the endpoint directly without going through this proxy the response is also JSON. I'm setting the Content-Type header to `application/json`